# How to create NuGet package that targets .NET 5 or below. But not .NET 6 or above

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, .net-5, .net-6.0

I've a scenario where the nuget package should be allowed to be referenced on .NET 5 or below projects. But not on .NET 6 and above.

The reason being, [my library](https://github.com/soundaranbu/RazorTemplating) works until .NET 5 but breaks in .NET 6. Although I've documented it, I want to prevent the users from installing the wrong version. Do we have a way to achieve this?

**Some more clarity on the scenario:**

- I had a version `v1.5.0` of my library that multi targets `net5.0`, `netcoreapp3.1` & `netcoreapp3.0`. I understand that this version can be used by the upcoming versions of .NET.
- When .NET 6 came up, `v1.5.0` broke. It doesn't work in .NET 6
- Now I fixed the issues & released `v1.7.0` for .NET 6. This time it only targets `net6.0` (Not multi targeting for lower versions. Due to maintainance reasons.).
- So, .NET 5 users will keep using `v1.5.0` & .NET 6 users should be using `v1.7.0`. I've documented the preferred version for each TargetFrameworks.
- Now, any issues related to `v1.5.0` on .NET 5 & below will be released as `v1.6.x`. When I do these releases, I want to prevent the users of .NET 6 from installing it accidently.
- Even if the users installed the wrong version and when they build the project, it should throw error saying that they should update the version to `v1.7.0` (Prevention at the build time, instead of runtime)

Comment: If your package depends on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` you can specify an upper limit

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible. Any package targeting .NET 5 can be consumed by .NET 6 (and above) projects. So you are not describing a valid scenario above.

Comment: Hi @lex-li, I edited the question to give you more clarity on the scenario.

Comment: @SoundarAnbu You can only prevent .NET 5 users from consuming your v1.7 version, but you cannot prevent .NET 6 users from using v1.5. "I've documented the preferred version for each TargetFrameworks" is all you can do.

Answer (score 1):

As Lex Li's answer implies, NuGet does not provide a way for package installation/restore to fail when a net6.0 or above project references your package. Higher versions of the same target framework identifier are, by design, considered compatible.

But what you can do is include `build/net6.0/<packageid>.targets` in your package, and have a target that runs before/after build that uses `<Error Message="..." />` saying that the higher package version is required for this target framework. You might need to also include `buildTransitive/net6.0/<packageid>.targets` to make sure this still works if your package is a transitive dependency in a project, rather than referenced directly.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out.